# How to pass Javascript object to controller?

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel form that looks like this...

```
 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'SitesController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'sites_create_form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/formdata']) !!}

 {{Form::label('s_name', 'Site Name')}}
                {{Form::text('s_name', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Site Name'])}}

 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I also have a Javascript object containing an array of image ids, I would like to pass this to the controller so I can process the ids and add them to the resulting site.

I am thinking that the best option is to echo the array to a hidden form field and do it that way?

Is there a better way to do it, can I pass the javascript object directly to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ajax requests, you could dynamically add the array of IDs to the form data before sending the request. I assume since you're using the form builder you aren't doing that.

Since you are most likely just sending the form "normally" then you answered your own question. Add a hidden field that includes the array as the value.

Make sure to sanitize input, just in case somebody changes the value of the field.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the best use for my particular scenario but wanted some confimation.  Thanks for the sanitize tip

Comment: @fightstarr20 if my answer solved your question (which it sounds like it did) please don't just up-vote it, accept the answer as well so other people see it.